# FTPClient: how to "storeFile" with a file that has line breaks?

Tags: java, newline

I'm trying to use FTPclient to upload a .txt file to my website's FTP server.  The following code is just a snippet and does compile and run fine.

```
System.out.println("Connecting to the FTP server...");
client.connect("---.com"); //Host and login information excluded
client.login("---", "---");//for security reasons
System.out.println("Login successful.");            
System.out.println("Uploading file.");
client.setFileType(FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);
OutputStream o = client.storeFileStream("test.csv");
fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
String s;

//Attempting to use BufferedReader to read a line and write it to OutputStream
while((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    o.write(s.getBytes());
    String nl = "\r\n";    //Writing the new line character.
    o.write(nl.getBytes());
}

o.close();
System.out.println("Done!  Terminating connection.");
client.completePendingCommand();
client.logout();
```

The variable "filePath" is set to the path a temporary .txt file that contains the following:

```
1. Line one.
2. Line two.
3. Line three.
```

But, when I FTP my file to my server, download it, and view it.  It is printed like this:

```
1. Line one.2. Line two.3.Line three.
```

What I'm suspecting here is that it's just reading all of the bytes of the file and completely disregarding line breaks.  I need to have the line breaks in the output file because as you can see, my export format is .csv, which requires each product (ie a shirt with its attributes separated by commas) to have its own line and separated by commas.

Any idea how I would achieve this using InputStream and OutputStream?

Comment: How try with `String n1 = System.getProperty("line.separator");`?

Comment: Just reading the documentation of [storeFileStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#storeFileStream(java.lang.String)) would suggest that you just use `"\n"` instead of `"\r\n"`.

Comment: Where you are setting the file type, is there an option to set it to binary? This will ensure that no textual/character interpretation/conversion is done to the data.

Comment: I just tried it with "\n" and although I write "\n" to the OutputStream, my test.csv file still contains the same output above (without the "\n" character).  Any other ideas?

Comment: The file type is set in line 6.  "client.setFileType(FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE)"

In this file type, when I write "\n", it doesn't appear in the output file so I assume it's recognizing it, but just not actually going to the next line.  Please read my reply above this one for more info about this.